# How to read in an environment variable for Jinja2 so that it can be interpolated in an if condition?

Tags: python, jinja2

I try to wrap-around my head on how to skip certain parts of code based on an environment variable when using a `Jinja2` template to generate a file with a `YAML` document. I did some research online, asked ChatGPT, but I did not find any answer that helped me.

So I made this minimal example:

```py
import os
from jinja2 import Template


os.environ['SKIP']="False"
print(
    Template(
        "{% if env['SKIP'] %}\n"
        '{{ "do not skip" }}\n'
        "{% else %}\n"
        '{{ "skip" }}\n'
        "{% endif %}"
    ).render(env=os.environ)
)
```

outputs `do not skip` (as expected).

Executing the following:

```py
import os
os.environ['SKIP']="True"

print(
    Template(
        "{% if env['SKIP'] %}\n"
        '{{ "do not skip" }}\n'
        "{% else %}\n"
        '{{ "skip" }}\n'
        "{% endif %}"
    ).render(env=os.environ)
)
```

also returns `do not skip`, but I expected `skip`. So I assume it is not reading the environment variable correctly.

How can I use environment variables in Jinja2 correctly? And how to fix this minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues here - I think your logic is backwards for skipping, you properly intended this:

```
print(
    Template(
        "{% if env['SKIP'] %}\n"
        '{{ "skip" }}\n'
        "{% else %}\n"
        '{{ "do not skip" }}\n'
        "{% endif %}"
    ).render(env=os.environ)
)
```

Secondly, to my knowledge, in python all strings except the empty string will evaluate to a truthy value. So, for instance,

```
if "False":
    print('hi')
```

Will output "hi".

Since it seems environment variables in this context can only be string values, you should check for equality with the string "True" to reach the desired behavior:

```
import os

os.environ['SKIP']="False"

print(
    Template(
        "{% if env['SKIP'] == 'True' %}\n"
        '{{ "skip" }}\n'
        "{% else %}\n"
        '{{ "do not skip" }}\n'
        "{% endif %}"
    ).render(env=os.environ)
)
```

Comment: Environment variables need to be set as string. If you were to run your code in a Jupyter notebook, you would get: `TypeError: str expected, not bool`.

Comment: In that case, change your condition to `{% if env['SKIP'] == 'True' %}` @mgross

Comment: wow, that works. I really did not really that this will make all the difference. Will test it tomorrow in the real code to see if that resolves my problem. If yes, will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is the solution (the edited version) that I needed, thanks!